# Find the measure of the image of a triangle under a linear transformation

Tags: integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

> Let $L: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2 : [x,y] \to [x+2y,-x+2y]$ and $A =  \{[x,y]:x \ge 0, 0 \le y \le 2-x\}$. Find measure of $L(A)$.

How do I solve this? My thought is:
$u = x+2y, v=-x+2y$, transform  $\{x \ge 0, 0 \le y \le 2-x\}$  to match $u$ and $v$ (find image B) and then find ${\int \int}_B du dv$. Is my line of thought correct?
(I am sure that measure in question is Jordan measure.)

Comment: Think geometrically. A measure in $\Bbb R^2$ of a simple geometrical shape is simply its area. $A$ is a triangle, and $L$ is a linear transformation. Draw $L(A)$ on a piece of paper, and find its area.

Comment: Hint: linear mappngs take lines to lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Geometric approach

The set $A$ is the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(2,0)$, $(0,2)$. Its image under $L$ (which is a linear transformation) is a triangle with vertices $L(0,0)$, $L(2,0)$, $L(0,2)$. You can find the area of that triangle using a formula from Euclidean geometry.

#### Analytic approach

The area is 
 $$\iint_{L(A)}1\,  du\,dv = \iint_A \left|\frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (x,y)}\right|\,dy\,dx$$
where $\frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (x,y)}$ is the Jacobian determinant (look up the change of variable formula). The latter integral can be found in the calculus way, or also with the help of geometry: it's just the area of $A$ times the (constant) value $\left|\frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (x,y)}\right|$.

Answer (score 0):

the area(2) of your triangle gets multiplied by the determinant(4) of the transformation represented by the matrix $\pmatrix{1 & 2 \\ -1 & 2}.$